# With Google Appscript - How to send a automated email using a custom body from a draft template located in Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I've got an simple automated email messaging api up and running. However, I want the "body" of the message to be something more complicated than just unformatted text.  My code uses data from google sheets and is as follows:

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("msg");
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(e.parameter.name);
  var headings = rows[0].map(String.toLowerCase);
  Logger.log(headings);
  var holder = [];
  for(x in headings)
  {
    Logger.log(headings[x]);
    var output = (headings[x] in e.parameters) ? e.parameter[headings[x]] : 'none';
    if (headings[x] == 'id'){ output = getRandom();}
    if (headings[x] == 'timestamp'){ output = new Date();}
    holder.push(output);
  }
  Logger.log("The holder contains the following: " + holder);
  Logger.log(holder.length);
  sheet.appendRow(holder);

  var lRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  Logger.log('HEADING IS: ' + headings[1] + ' ' + lRow + ' ' + sheet.getRange(lRow, 2).getValue());

  var tempMsg = GmailApp.getDraft()[0].getMessage();

  MailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange(lRow, 2).getValue(),'mo@example.co.uk', 'Thank you for signing up!!', tempMsg.getBody());

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
    'status' : 'success',
    'lastRow' : lRow ,
    'INFO' : holder
  }))
}
```

With the above code, I tried emailing myself and do not get an email. If i delete the "var tempMsg..." and and replace the final property of MailApp.SendEmail (tempMsg.getBody()) to any string - it does work.

The idea is to use the body of a draft email in my Gmail drafts folder as the body of the new automated email.

I went through the api and tried different methods like GmailApp.getDraft(id).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the mistype, ``getDraft()`` of ``GmailApp.getDraft()[0].getMessage()`` is [``getDrafts()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getDrafts()). By the way, when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy it as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: I did redeploy it and I it doesn't work. I made a html form with a bit of jQuery to make use of the code above. What did work is that information written on the form is stored on a Google sheet. The automated email didn't work. I may be wrong but doesn't getDrafts() return an array of drafts? I used getDrafts()[0].getMessage() to return the body of my recent draft message in my draft inbox.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Can you add your current script to your question? ``getDrafts()`` returns "GmailDraft[]" which is an array of Gmail draft messages. You can see the official document of ``getDrafts()`` at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getDrafts()).

Comment: I've made some progress. I've managed to learn how to add html/css styling to the body of my email and it works:

`var htmlmsg = "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>This is the heading</h1><br/><p>Body Text</p>";
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange(lRow, 2).getValue(), 'Thank you for signing up!!', htmlmsg, {htmlBody:htmlmsg});`
`
How do you create html in a separate file and use it in the MailApp function? I want to incoroprate images etc... Is this possible. Let me know @Tanaike.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Can you post the solution as an answer and accept it? By this, other users can see your issue as the resolved question.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress. I've managed to learn how to add html/css styling to the body of my email and it works. This doesn't answer the question exactly but the result is what i wanted.

`var htmlmsg = "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>This is the heading</h1><br/><p>Body Text</p>"; 
MailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange(lRow, 2).getValue(), 'Thank you for signing up!!', htmlmsg, {htmlBody:htmlmsg});`